# When is this braiding not a symmetry?

Tags: braided-tensor-categories, higher-category-theory, ct.category-theory, at.algebraic-topology

Given a topological space $X$ instead of forming the fundamental groupoid $\pi(X)$ which is the category whose objects are the points and morphisms the homotopy classes of paths one can also form the fundamental 2-groupoid which is the bicategory with objects = points, 1-morphisms = paths and 2-morphisms = homotopy classes of homotopies between paths. Composition of 1-morphisms is the "standard" composition $a\otimes b$ of paths given by $(a\otimes b)(t) = a(2t)$ for $0 \leq t \leq \frac{1}{2}$ and $(a\otimes b)(t) = b(2t-1)$ for $\frac{1}{2} \leq t \leq 1$.

By restricting to loops around a fixed point $e \in X$ one therefore gets a bicategory with one object, i.e., a monoidal category.
When moreover $X$ has the structure of a topological monoid it is easy to see that the structure map $\mu: X \times X \rightarrow X$ induces a braiding $\gamma_{a,b}: a\otimes b \stackrel{\sim}{\rightarrow} b\otimes a$ on this monoidal category.

My question is: Is there an (elementary) example where this braiding is not a symmetry? One obvious necessary condition is that $X$ has to be noncommutative in order to give such an example.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If $X=\Omega Y$, that braided monoidal category (indeed groupoid) classifies the homotopy type of $P_3Y$, the $3$-type of $Y$. Such $3$-type is completely determined by the map $\eta^*\colon \pi_2(Y)\rightarrow \pi_3(Y)$ defined by precomposition with the Hopf map $\eta\colon S^3\rightarrow S^2$. This map is quadratic, i.e. $\eta^* (x)=\eta^* (-x)$ and the map defined by 
$\eta^* (x|y)=\eta^* (x+y)-\eta^* (x)-\eta^* (y)$ is bilinear. One can recover this map from the monoidal category, essentially $\eta^*(x)$ corresponds to the braiding $\gamma_{x,x}\colon x\otimes x\cong x\otimes x$. The category is symmetric if and only if $\eta^* $ is a homomorphism. This does not always happen, since any quadratic map between abelian groups $A\rightarrow B$ can be realized by some appropriate $Y$. For instance, if you take $Y=S^2$ the quadratic map is $\eta^* \colon \mathbb{Z}\rightarrow \mathbb{Z}$ is $\eta^* (n)=n^2$, hence you get an example.

Comment: Very nice! Do you know a good reference for the relation between braided monoidal categories and homotopy 3-types?

Comment: Thanks Nicolas, unfortunately this is a typical example of theory which is "well known to experts". Despite being easy and beautiful there's no monograph covering for instance what you ask. See section 3 of Berger's "Double loop spaces, braided monoidal categories and algebraic 3-type of space" and references therein.

Comment: Isn't it true that when X is itself a topological monoid (and not just a loop space) the quadratic map eta* is in fact a homomorphism? In any case I think one can use the monoid product to show that the braiding is its own homotopy inverse whenever X is a topological monoid.

Comment: @Carl, that's not true, for any loop space has the homotopy type of a topological group.

Comment: @Fernando, thanks, I see that now - the Moore loops and the ordinary loop space are of the same homotopy type. 

Comment: @ Fernando - I also see that I had calculated the obstruction to the braiding being a symmetry in terms of the monoid multiplication, an obstruction which, as you point out, is not zero in general.

Comment: @FErnando: Also relevant is our paper 
R. Brown and N.D. Gilbert  ``Algebraic models of 3-types and
automorphism  structures for crossed modules'', _Proc. London
Math. Soc._ (3) 59 (1989)  51-73. ([59] in my publication list, downloadable pdf). Of course J.-L. Loday got in earlier , in 1982, with his crossed squares as algebraic model of weak, pointed homotopy 3-types. These are exploited in G.R. Ellis, "Crossed squares and combinatorial homotopy". _Math. Z._ 214~(1) (1993) 93--110. The work of Loday generalises to higher dimensions. 

Comment: @Ronnie, there are few references dealing with crossed stuff and (braided/symmetric) monoidal categories at the same time. As you indicate, the literature on crossed stuff is more complete in connection with homotopy theory, and much of it is the work of yours and your collaborators. I think that Nicolas is looking for a reference written purely in the monoidal categorical setting. All I know goes through crossed stuff and through the 'well-known equivalence' with the monoidal setting. Do you happen to know a reference which suits Nicolas wishes?

Comment: @Fernando: I wonder if the 2011 Advances paper by Carrasco, Cegarra and garzon, Classifying spaces for braided monoidal categories and lax diagrams of bicategories, available as arXiv:0907.0930, is relevant? I confess to being behind on all this. Also there is material not written up on the homotopy double groupoid of a Hausdorff space, see TAC 14 (2005) 200-220, for example on tensor products. For me, the cubical theory is easier, especially when dealing with monoidal structures. Indeed, the paper with Gilbert might be easier working with double groupoids with connections, not as is!